# How to detect when the alert pop of In-App Purchase closed and completed purchase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I implemented In-App Purchase but can't detect when the user closed the alert and completed purchase. I want to check them and if they purchased an item, I want to show the log "purchased" on console.

Now `case .purchased :` in `func paymentQueue` was always through even the user doesn't purchase anything....

```
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing :
                break
            case .purchased :
                // always through here even user doesn't purchase items
                completeTransaction(transaction: transaction)

                print("purchased")

            case .failed :
                failedTransaction(transaction: transaction)
            case .restored :
                restoreTransaction(transaction: transaction)
            case .deferred :
                deferredTransaction(transaction: transaction)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using SwiftyStoreKit for doing IAP?

Comment: @Anuraj No, I use these code (https://qiita.com/hayashier/items/f05bd4a8bf3b3cefb072)

Comment: I guess u will get error in this delegate method. func purchaseManager(purchaseManager: SKPaymentManager, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    }

Comment: You should have a look here for a better way of doing In App Purchases I couldn't even follow the code you linked to. How does any of that even get initialized without an initializer? https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial

Comment: You won't get a transaction with a state of `.purchased` unless the user has made a purchase; check the product code that was purchased.

Comment: @Anuraj don't have any errors in delegate method.

Comment: @bao Have you assigned SKPaymentManager.shared().delegate = self in your viewController ?

Comment: @Anuraj Yes, I assigned it in the function that is excused the user touch Purchase button.